# VueJs, call a method from concatenated element

Tags: vue.js

I would like to call a method from a concatenated checkbox.

**here is my code:**

```
    methods: {          
     listServices(serviceId) {      
      axios
        .get(
          process.env.ROOT_API + "Service/List?Id=" + serviceId,
          this.$store.getters.getTokenHeaderFormData
        )
        .then(response => {             
          response.data.forEach(el => {    

            this.dataset.push([                         
              el.serviceName,              
              `<input type="checkbox" 
                onchange="${this.updateService(el.ServiceId)}">` // <-- Call UpdateService method
            ]);
          });

        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
    },
       updateService(serviceId){
          console.log(serviceId);
        },
```

The  `onchange="${this.updateService(el.ServiceId)}"` does not work. how can I do this?

Comment: Isn't the way you bind events in vue is `v-on:change` or `@change`. Can you try that.

Comment: I cannot contaminate those bind event, it does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this is to use `v-for`:

```
<template>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in dataset" :key="item[1]">
      <input type="checkbox" @change="updateService(item[1])">
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>

<script>
export default
{
  methods:
  {
    listServices(serviceId) 
    {      
      axios.get(
        process.env.ROOT_API + "Service/List?Id=" + serviceId,
        this.$store.getters.getTokenHeaderFormData
      ).then(response => 
      {             
        response.data.forEach(el => 
        {    
          this.dataset.push([                         
            el.serviceName,              
            el.ServiceId
          ]);
        });
      }).catch(error => 
      {
        console.log(error);
      });
    },
    updateService(serviceId)
    {
      console.log(serviceId);
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is not clear from the question. And it depends on the datatable implementation how it handles raw HTML. And in raw HTML you can put only vanilla JavaScript functions - they won't be bound to your Vue component.